# SwiftUI updating single @State property every second from Timer redraws a whole View also every second

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am not sure if I use it properly, but the case is the following:

I have a View:

```
struct TimerView: View {
    @State private var numberOfVideos: Int
    @State private var time = ""
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    init(numberOfVideos: Int) {
        _numberOfVideos = State(initialValue: numberOfVideos)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(time)
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                // it is called every second
                time = "00:00"
            }
        ReportView(numberOfVideos: $numberOfVideos)
    }
}

struct ReportView: View {
    @Binding private var numberOfVideos: Int
    init(numberOfVideos: Binding<Int>) {
        // ❌ this is called every second, I don't want it.
        self._numberOfVideos = numberOfVideos
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(String(numberOfVideos))
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
TimerView(numberOfVideos: 5)
```

Instantiating `ReportView` every second this is not what I need. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is nice article https://showmax.engineering/articles/unexpected-redrawing-in-swiftui

Comment: `TimelineView` is great for iOS 16+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jut move timer logic in separate view like this:

```
struct TimerView: View {
    @State private var numberOfVideos: Int
    @State private var time = ""

    init(numberOfVideos: Int) {
        _numberOfVideos = State(initialValue: numberOfVideos)
    }

    var body: some View {
        TimeText(text: $time)
        ReportView(numberOfVideos: $numberOfVideos)
            // .background(.debug)
    }
}

struct ReportView: View {
    @Binding private var numberOfVideos: Int
    init(numberOfVideos: Binding<Int>) {
        // ❌ this is called every second, I dont want it.
        self._numberOfVideos = numberOfVideos
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(String(numberOfVideos))
    }
}

struct TimeText: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .onReceive(timer) { t in
                // it is called every second
                text = t.debugDescription
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are storing `numberOfVideos` as `Binding` on `ReportView`.

You should only use `Binding` to inject mutable state into subviews, which you want to redraw whenever that mutable state changes either from inside or outside the view.

Since you are never mutating `numberOfVideos` from inside `ReportView`, you should store it as an immutable property. If `TimerView` would update `numberOfVideos`, that would redraw the whole `TimerView` and hence create a new `ReportView` with the updated number as well.

This ensures that `ReportView` isn't recreated every time `time` is updated on `TimerView`.

```
struct ReportView: View {
  private let numberOfVideos: Int

  init(numberOfVideos: Int) {
    self.numberOfVideos = numberOfVideos
  }

  var body: some View {
    Text(String(numberOfVideos))
  }
}
```

Comment: My question was very simplified;) And, yes, I am mutating numberOfVideos from inside `ReportView`.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk then you've overly simplified your question and left out a key detail...